# Continuous $f : \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, can always find $\delta$ with $\delta < \epsilon$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, manifolds

I'm still new to rigorous proofs in multivariable calculus, does my attempt at the following work?

Let $f : \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f(\boldsymbol{0}) = 0$ and $f(\boldsymbol{x}) > 0$ otherwise.
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Let
$$m = \min_{{\Vert\boldsymbol{x}\Vert = \epsilon}} f(\boldsymbol{x})$$

Show that it is always possible to find $\delta$ with $0 < \delta < \epsilon$ such that when $\Vert \boldsymbol{x} \Vert < \delta$, we have $\Vert f(\boldsymbol{x})\Vert < m$.

My attempt:

The existence of a $\delta$ such that when $\Vert \boldsymbol{x} \Vert < \delta$, we have $\Vert f(\boldsymbol{x})\Vert < m$ follows trivially from the definition of continuity of $f$ at $0$. All that remains is to show that is possible to pick a $\delta$ with $\delta < \epsilon$.

Assume we are given such a $\delta_1$. We have $\delta_1 \leq \epsilon$, because $\Vert f(x)\Vert \geq m$ for $\Vert \boldsymbol{x} \Vert = \epsilon$.

If $\delta_1 < \epsilon$, let $\delta = \delta_1$ and we are done. Otherwise, $\delta_1 = \epsilon$, so choose $\delta = \frac{\delta_1}{2}$ and we are done.

Does that proof work? Is there a simpler way to express the "idea" I'm trying to get at (that we can always shrink our potential $\delta$ down until the strict inequality $\delta < \epsilon$ holds)?

Comment: Why not apply the definition of limit/continuity with $\epsilon = m/2$? This will be far more direct.

Comment: I don't see how that helps us bound $\delta$, sorry... could you give more detail?

Comment: The $\delta$ that works for $m/2$ will necessarily be less than your original $\epsilon$.

Comment: When I try this I still have the same issue I was encountering when I was doing the original proof. I try to show that $\delta < \epsilon$ by contradiction. This rules out $\epsilon > \delta$, but it doesn't seem like we can rule out $\delta = \epsilon$ by contradiction because our definition of $m$ is an equality constraint on $x$ and the limit definition is a strict inequality.

Comment: Should say rules out $\epsilon < \delta$**

Comment: If $\delta =\epsilon$, we have points $x$ with $\|f(x)\|<m/2$ arbitrarily close to points $y$ with $\|f(y)\|\ge m$. Doesn’t sound too continuous. Alternatively, you have by continuity that $\|f(x\|\le m/2$ when $\|x\|=\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused; this seems like it might be false. If $f$ is given radially by some sort of [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), then it seems like we could have $m=0$ at the radius $\epsilon$ (outside the bump) but positive values arbitrary close to $\mathbf x=\boldsymbol 0$. Have I missed a condition?

Comment: @Mark.S I'm the one who missed a condition, apologies. We also have $f(x) > 0$ for nonzero $x$. I've edited the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve your idea, rather than using [Ted](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin)'s idea from [the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998703/continuous-f-bbbrn-rightarrow-bbbr-can-always-find-delta-with#comment8252634_3998703), then instead of writing out the "if...then" explicitly, you could set $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\epsilon/2)$.

Comment: That's better! Thanks!